# Passing data using delegates

Tags: swift

I'm trying to pass data between A & C, where A is the first controller and C is the third controller. Now I know how to pass data from A to B & B to A, where you create a protocol in B and create a delegate inside the view controller. That looks something like this.

A controller

```
class AController: UIViewController, BControllerDelegate {
  func bControllerButtonPress() {
    view.backgroundColor = .red
  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowBController" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! BController
        vc.delegate = self
    }
  }

  @IBAction func showBController() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowBController", sender: nil)
  }
}
```

B Controller

```
protocol BControllerDelegate {
  func bControllerButtonPress()
}

class BController: UIViewController {
  var delegate: BControllerDelegate?

  @IBAction func buttonPress() {
    delegate?.bControllerButtonPress()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Now how would I do this with C Controller or even a D Controller. Cause I have a navigation controller, where in controller C I create a new Item and pop to the root view controller. Then I would like to change the UI, but can't seem to figure it out. Would really appreciate the help.

**More Detail Explanation**

Controller A, login controller which has a sign up button that takes me to Controller B. Controller B, email controller. Controller C, username/name controller. Controller D, password controller. So from controller B, I pass the email to controller C and so on until Controller D. This is where I create the new User. When the new user is created in the Controller D, I pop to the root view controller. Then this is were I would like to perform a segue to Controller E from Controller A, once the new user is created in Controller D. Controller A,B,C,D are all in one navigation controller.

So looking at @bsod and @Caleb answers it seems that I either pass a delegate or a data model between my A-B-C-D controllers?

Comment: how u poping to root viewcontrolelr..?

Comment: navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

Comment: if you are not keeping any reference when popping. Notification Center with observer is the way to pass the data. post a notification to notification center just before popping view controller, observe the notification in viewdidload of the root view controller.

Comment: how do you navigate to controller C ? I mean which controller is it's parent

Comment: @andesta.erfan I navigate from B controller to C controller by a show/push segue. A is the root view controller of the navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

> Now how would I do this with C Controller or even a D Controller.

This is a good reason to organize your app around a [data model](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html). The app delegate or first view controller can create the model, which should contain the data and business logic for the app. Each view controller passes a reference to the model to any other view controllers it creates, and then you don't have to worry much about passing data between view controllers. If your view controller C or D make some changes to the model, they don't need to be handed back to A explicitly... A just automatically gets the updated data by virtue of talking to the same data model that C or D use.

Here's a concrete example. Let's say you're building an organizer for salespeople. So your data model might be called `OrganizerModel`, and it'll include a list of `customers`. You can tap on a button to see all the customer locations on a map, and then you can tap on a particular location on the map to see and edit the customer data. So, how should those changes get communicated back to the rest of the app? Let's imagine that there's a `MainViewController` that shows the app's main view and lets you access the customer list, supplier list, product catalog, calendar, etc. When you tap a button to look at the customer list, `MainViewController` segues to `CustomerListViewController`, and in `prepare(for:sender:)` it does something like:

```
guard let customerListController = segue.destinationController as CustomerListViewController else {
   //...
}
customerListController.customerList = self.organizerModel.customerList
```

So now the customer list controller has access to the list of customers, which is all it needs to do its thing. From there, the user can tap a button to see all the customers on a map, and when that happens the `CustomerListViewController` segues to a `CustomerMapViewController`, again doing something like:

```
guard let customerMapController = segue.destinationController as CustomerMapViewController else {
   //...
}
customerMapController.customerList = self.customerList
```

So the CustomerMapViewController shows a map, including little icons for each customer, and when the user taps on one of those it segues to a CustomerViewController, which only needs a single customer's record to do everything it does:

```
guard let customerController = segue.destinationController as CustomerProfileViewController else {
   //...
}
customerController.customer = self.customerList[selectedCustomer]
```

Now we've got a situation like your `A->B->C->D` case, where a view controller several jumps away from the first one is changing some data. But when `CustomerProfileViewController` makes some changes to its `customer`, there's no need to send that information all the way back to `MainViewController`, because `MainViewController` and `CustomerProfileViewController` are both using the same data; it's `customer` is part of the overall model that `MainViewController` uses.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code. Would appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks @Caleb, for taking the time to reply to my question. Can you check at the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly to answer your question, delegates can be chained with or without a protocol. With a protocol:

```
protocol DoSomething: AnyObject {
    func doSomething()
}
class VCA: UIViewController, DoSomething {
    func doSomething() {
        print("do something")
    }
    func push() {
        let b = VCB()
        b.delegate = self
    }
}
class VCB: UIViewController, DoSomething {
    weak var delegate: DoSomething?
    func doSomething() {
        delegate?.doSomething()
    }
    func push() {
        let c = VCC()
        c.delegate = delegate // instead of declaring self as the delegate
                              // you can declare the delegate (which is VCA)
    }
}
class VCC: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: DoSomething?
    func doSomething() {
        delegate?.doSomething()
    }
}
```

You can also ditch the protocol and just type the delegate to the first view controller:

```
class VCA: UIViewController {
    func doSomething() {
        print("do something")
    }
    func push() {
        let b = VCB()
        b.delegate = self
    }
}
class VCB: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: VCA?
    func push() {
        let c = VCC()
        c.delegate = delegate
    }
}
class VCC: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: VCA?
    func doSomething() {
        delegate?.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Give careful thought to how you architect your view controllers and pass data as the delegate pattern is not the only option--however, it is the bedrock.

Comment: Thanks @bsod, for taking the time to reply to my question. Can you check at the edited question.

Comment: From your description, it appears that the ideal solution would be to pass a data object forward from A through D with each controller adding to that object. Once that object reaches D and is completed, you can pass that completed object back to A through a delegate.

Answer (score -1):

You may have other option to do this,
First one: you have to create your delegates from A to B and then again B to C. (If you do not want that your view controller B would appear than animation false would suggested)

Or you can choose create Notification Bus between the ciew controllers 
You can use the "NotificationCenter" method for it.Where you define the same observer and receiver in it and you will get the controll of the class where you have define the receiver of that notification.

Please be remove all the notification observer while pushing the new view controller.